# how manipulate a NSDictionary generated by a json file in swift

Tags: swift, ios8

I've a NSDictionary populated by a JSON file.
JSON file content (initially)

```
{
"length" : 0, 
"locations" : []
}
```

I want add some elements in "locations". The elements have the below structure:

```
[
"name" : "some_name", 
"lat" : "4.88889", 
"long" : "5.456789", 
"date" : "19/01/2015"
]
```

In next code I read de JSON File

```
let contentFile = NSData(contentsOfFile: pathToTheFile)
let jsonDict = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(contentFile!, options: nil, error: &writeError) as NSDictionary`
```

like you can see `jsonDict` contain the JSON's info but in a NSDictionary object.

At this point I can't add the elements mentioned before, I tried insert NSData, NSArray, Strings, and nothing results for me

After do this I want convert "final" NSDictionary in JSON again to save it in a file.

The "final" NSDictionary must be like this

```
{
"length" : 3, 
"locations" : [
    {
    "name" : "some_name", 
    "lat" : "4.88889", 
    "long" : "5.456789", 
    "date" : "19/01/2015"
    },
    {
    "name" : "some_name_2", 
    "lat" : "8.88889", 
    "long" : "9.456789", 
    "date" : "19/01/2015"
    },
    {
    "name" : "some_name_3", 
    "lat" : "67.88889", 
    "long" : "5.456789", 
    "date" : "19/01/2015"
    }
]
}
```

"length" control the  index for new element

I have no more ideas to do this. thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to be able to modify the dictionary, you can make it mutable:

```
let jsonDict = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(contentFile!, options: .MutableContainers, error: &writeError) as NSMutableDictionary
```

The resulting `NSMutableDictionary` can be modified. For example:

```
let originalJSON = "{\"length\" : 0,\"locations\" : []}"
let data = originalJSON.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)
var parseError: NSError?
let locationDictionary = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: .MutableContainers, error: &parseError) as NSMutableDictionary

locationDictionary["length"] = 1        // change the `length` value

let location1 = [                       // create dictionary that we'll insert
    "name" : "some_name",
    "lat"  : "4.88889",
    "long" : "5.456789",
    "date" : "19/01/2015"
]

if let locations = locationDictionary["locations"] as? NSMutableArray {
    locations.addObject(location1)      // add the location to the array of locations
}
```

If you now constructed JSON from the updated `locationDictionary`, it would look like:

```
{
    "length" : 1,
    "locations" : [
        {
            "long" : "5.456789",
            "lat" : "4.88889",
            "date" : "19/01/2015",
            "name" : "some_name"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: hi Rob I can´t understand yet :(. I tried that you said but no results.
How can do a new NSDictionary that finally will be my JSON file

Comment: See example in revised answer.